# createBrowserHistory is undefined in history import for React Router DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, history.js

I'm currently using v5 of React Router DOM. My goal is to create a history object so that I can manipulate my page locations in my redux actions. In past projects I imported the `createBrowserHistory` function as so:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

With this setup though I get the deprecation warning:

```
Warning: Please use `require("history").createBrowserHistory` instead of `require("history/createBrowserHistory")`. Support for the latter will be removed in the next major release.
```

I changed my import to just:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history';
```

But at this point `createBrowserHistory` comes up as `undefined`. I'm at a loss at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is what my `yarn.lock` file looks like:

```
react-router-dom@^5.1.2:
  version "5.1.2"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-router-dom/-/react-router-dom-5.1.2.tgz#06701b834352f44d37fbb6311f870f84c76b9c18"
  integrity sha512-7BPHAaIwWpZS074UKaw1FjVdZBSVWEk8IuDXdB+OkLb8vd/WRQIpA4ag9WQk61aEfQs47wHyjWUoUGGZxpQXew==
  dependencies:
    "@babel/runtime" "^7.1.2"
    history "^4.9.0"
    loose-envify "^1.3.1"
    prop-types "^15.6.2"
    react-router "5.1.2"
    tiny-invariant "^1.0.2"
    tiny-warning "^1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import history from 'history';
var createBrowserHistory = history.createBrowserHistory
```

or

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
```

Comment: No luck with either. For the first I get: `Cannot read property 'createBrowserHistory' of undefined`. For the second: I get `"export 'createBrowserHistory' was not found in 'history'`